# Dynamic Tabs and dynamic content from mySQL

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, tabs

Using CodeIgniter, I have a set of tabs with titles taken from a table on my DB.
When I click a certain tab, it loads a content which is also
from another table on my DB.

I know the second part will need something like ajax. But I'm really confused on how to do this in an MVC way.

I tried creating a controller which would fetch the title of the tabs from my model, then load a view passing the data fetch from my model as params. Now, I created the tab, but dynamically changing the content when clicked is where I'm stuck.

Anyone can at least tell me the basic idea on how to achieve this?
Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

lets look at this example may be it will help you

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="fetchdata(<?=$id?>)">Tab 1</a>
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="fetchdata(<?=$id?>)">Tab 2</a>
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="fetchdata(<?=$id?>)">Tab 3</a>
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="fetchdata(<?=$id?>)">Tab 4</a>
// where $id is value on which you have to execute query anfdfetech data from DB
// here is JS function with ajax call
<script type="text/javascript">
 function fetchdata(id){

         $.ajax({
        type:"POST", url:"<?php echo base_url()?>controllername/functionname,
        data:"&id=" + id,
        complete:function (data) {
        alert(data.responseText);               
        //or here what you want to do with ajax response, like put content in any html tag
        $('#htmlidoftag').html(data.responseText);//like this
        }
    });
 }
</script>
// here is the php function within controller
function functionname()
{
    // First, delete old captchas
$id= $_REQUEST['id']
$response = $this->model->model_function($id);
// in model function run your query to fetch data   
echo $response ;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I think I'm going on the right path now. I'll try to figure out how to implement this with a UI framework. I was initially using foundation from zurb and was using their tabs but I think I will have to modify a lot if I'll push through with that framework?

Comment: always welcome i have showed only the demo not a perfect code but this can guide you that how you can use with CI